# programming for js arcgis map

Tags: javascript, html, gis, arcgis-js-api

`I'm able to create my own basemap that already build with extent map, maptoggle & basemap gallery and some other widgets(refer image 1).

However, I'm still as a problem to integrate the widget for the timeslidder with the basemap (the given source code) no matter how i tries.

i also attach the link for the source of the timeslidder widget (for your reference) that i want to intergrate with the code i paste here.

[

```
<html>
```

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Well completion dates for the Hugoton Gas Field Over Time</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.30/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.30/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body, 

  #mapDiv {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
  }

  #mapDiv {
    position: relative;
  }

  #bottomPanel {
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: -500px;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 2.5em;
  }

  #timeInfo{
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: solid 2px #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 99;
  }

    #bottomPanel2 {
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: -500px;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 8.5em;
    }

   #timeInfo2{
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: solid 2px #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 99;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.30/"></script>
<script>
  var map;
  require([
    "esri/map", 
    "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer", 
    "esri/geometry/Extent", 
    "esri/SpatialReference", 
    "esri/TimeExtent", 
    "esri/dijit/TimeSlider",
    "dojo/_base/array", 
    "dojo/dom", 
    "dojo/domReady!",

    "dojo/on",
    "esri/tasks/query", "esri/tasks/QueryTask"
  ], function(
    Map, 
    ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, 
    Extent, 
    SpatialReference,
    TimeExtent, 
    TimeSlider,
    arrayUtils, 
    dom,on, Query, QueryTask
  ) 

  {
    var myextent = new Extent(92.14339937585252, -4.921857675800532,  125.89339937584356,11.56021935381215,  new SpatialReference({ wkid:4326 }));
        map = new Map("mapDiv", 
        {
            basemap: "topo",
            extent: myextent, // funct:variable
            //center; [103.8999, 1.7381] // longitude, latitude Mas
            zoom: 6
        });

    var opLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://175.136.253.77/arcgis/rest/services/CAQM/CAQM_Current_Reading/MapServer");
        opLayer.setVisibleLayers([0]);

    //apply a definition expression so only some features are shown 
    var layerDefinitions = [];
        layerDefinitions[0] = "FIELD_KID=1000148164";
        opLayer.setLayerDefinitions(layerDefinitions);

        //add the gas fields layer to the map 
        map.addLayers([opLayer]);

    map.on("layers-add-result", initSlider);
    map.on("layers-add-result", initSlider2);

    function initSlider() 
    { 
        var timeSlider = new TimeSlider({
            style: "width: 100%;"
        }, dom.byId("timeSliderDiv"));
          map.setTimeSlider(timeSlider);

        var timeExtent = new TimeExtent();
          timeExtent.startTime = new Date("01/01/1927 UTC");
          timeExtent.endTime = new Date("12/01/1927 UTC");
          timeSlider.setThumbCount(1);// Assuming slider has only one thumb:
          timeSlider.createTimeStopsByTimeInterval(timeExtent, 1, "esriTimeUnitsMonths");
          timeSlider.setThumbIndexes([0,1]);
          timeSlider.setThumbMovingRate(1000);//for 2 sec
          timeSlider.startup();

        //add labels for every other time stop
        var labels = arrayUtils.map(timeSlider.timeStops, function(timeStop,i) 
        { 
            if ( i % 1 === 0 ) {
              return timeStop.getUTCMonth()+1; //to get the sliding timeline bcz getUTCMonth start from zero array
            } else {
              return "";
            }
        }); 

        timeSlider.setLabels(labels);

        timeSlider.on("time-extent-change", function(evt) {
          console.log(startTime.getUTCMonth());
            var startValString = evt.startTime.getUTCMonth();
            var endValString = evt.endTime.getUTCMonth();
            dom.byId("daterange").innerHTML = "<i>" + startValString + " and " + endValString + "<\/i>";
            console.log(startValString);
          });
    }

    function initSlider2() 
    {   var timeSlider = new TimeSlider({
            style: "width: 100%;"
            }, dom.byId("timeSliderDiv2"));
            map.setTimeSlider(timeSlider);

        var timeExtent = new TimeExtent();
            timeExtent.startTime = new Date("1/1/1927 UTC");
            timeExtent.endTime = new Date("1/31/1927 UTC");
            timeSlider.setThumbCount(1);// Assuming slider has only one thumb:
            timeSlider.createTimeStopsByTimeInterval(timeExtent, 1, "esriTimeUnitsDays");
            timeSlider.setThumbIndexes([0,1]);
            timeSlider.setThumbMovingRate(2000);//for 2 sec
            timeSlider.startup();

        //add labels for every other time stop
        var labels2 = arrayUtils.map(timeSlider.timeStops, function(timeStop, i) 
        { let ii = i+1;
            //console.log(timeStop);console.log(ii);
            if ( i % 1 === 0 ) {
                //return timeStop.getUTCDay(); 
                return ii; 
            }   else {
              return "";
                }
        }); 

        timeSlider.setLabels(labels2);

            timeSlider.on("time-extent-change", function(evt) {
            var startValString = evt.startTime.getUTCDay();
            var endValString = evt.endTime.getUTCDay();
            dom.byId("daterange2").innerHTML //= "<i>" + startValString + " and " + endValString  + "<\/i>";
          });
    }

    var queryTask = new QueryTask
        ("http://175.136.253.77/arcgis/rest/services/CAQM/CAQM_CO/MapServer/0");

      var query = new Query();
      query.where = '1=1';
      query.where = dom.byId("state").value;
      query.returnGeometry = false;
      query.outFields = //["*"];
      [ //from the choosen data
        "ID", "STATION_ID", "STATION_LOCATION", "PLACE", 
        "LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"
      ];

    //on(dom.byId("execute"), "click", execute);
    document.getElementById("execute_bttn").onclick = function() {execute_result()};

      function execute_result () 
      { 
        <!-- query.text = dom.byId("state").value; -->
        query.text = document.getElementById("state").value;
        queryTask.execute(query, showResults);

        function showResults (results) 
          { 
            var resultItems = [];
            var resultCount = results.features.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) 
            {
              var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
              for (var attr in featureAttributes) 
              {
                resultItems.push("<b>" + attr + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[attr] + "<br>");
              }
              resultItems.push("<br>");
            }

            //dom.byId("info").innerHTML = resultItems.join("");
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = resultItems.join("");

          }

       }    


  });
</script>
```

```
<!-- <div> <input type = "button" id = "MonthButton" value= "MONTH"></div> -->

<div id="mapDiv">

    <div id = "slist">STATION LIST :
        <input type="text" id="state" placeholder="State"> 
        <input id="execute_bttn" type="button" value="FIND"> 
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="info" style="padding:5px; margin:5px; background-color:#eee;">
        <br />
        <br /></div> 
    </div>

  <div id="bottomPanel">
    <div id="timeInfo">
      <div>Month in 1927 <span id="daterange">From Jan - Dec</span> (Completion date)</div>
      <div id="timeSliderDiv"></div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div id="bottomPanel2">
    <div id="timeInfo2">
      <div>Dates For <span id="daterange2">January 1927</span> (Completion date)</div>
      <div id="timeSliderDiv2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any error in the console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Comment: I can't see where you are creating the time slider in your code. You should add that part to the question.

Comment: i edit the code alrdy. perhaps u can try to check it (?) bcz i still cant find the prob eventho i alrdy altered it (the same error keep appearing)

Answer (score 0):

I got it already.

Here is the code when I integrate the gis js timeslidder with my api data.
Hopefully this would help other fresh grads like me, who work as gis programmer.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Well completion dates for the Hugoton Gas Field Over Time</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.30/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.30/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, 
   
   #mapDiv {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
      }

      #mapDiv {
        position: relative;
      }

      #bottomPanel {
        left: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-left: -500px;
        position: absolute; 
        bottom: 2.5em;
      }

      #timeInfo{
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: solid 2px #ccc;
        background-color: #fff;
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 1000px;
        z-index: 99;
      }
   
    #bottomPanel2 {
        left: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-left: -500px;
        position: absolute; 
        bottom: 8.5em;
  }
   
    #timeInfo2{
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: solid 2px #ccc;
        background-color: #fff;
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 1000px;
        z-index: 99;
  }
    </style>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.30/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      require([
        "esri/map", 
        "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer", 
        "esri/geometry/Extent", 
        "esri/SpatialReference", 
        "esri/TimeExtent", 
        "esri/dijit/TimeSlider",
        "dojo/_base/array", 
  
        "esri/tasks/query", "esri/tasks/QueryTask"
      ], function(
        Map, 
        ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, 
  Extent, 
        SpatialReference,
        TimeExtent, 
        TimeSlider,
        arrayUtils, Query, QueryTask
      ) 
      
      {
        var myextent = new Extent(92.14339937585252, -4.921857675800532,  125.89339937584356,11.56021935381215,  new SpatialReference({ wkid:4326 }));
   map = new Map("mapDiv", 
   {
    basemap: "topo",
    extent: myextent, // funct:variable
    //center; [103.8999, 1.7381] // longitude, latitude Mas
    zoom: 6
   });
  
  var opLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://175.136.253.77/arcgis/rest/services/CAQM/CAQM_Current_Reading/MapServer");
   opLayer.setVisibleLayers([0]);

  //apply a definition expression so only some features are shown 
  var layerDefinitions = [];
   layerDefinitions[0] = "FIELD_KID=1000148164";
   opLayer.setLayerDefinitions(layerDefinitions);

   //add the gas fields layer to the map 
   map.addLayers([opLayer]);

  map.on("layers-add-result", initSlider);
  map.on("layers-add-result", initSlider2);
   
  function initSlider() 
  { 
   var timeSlider = new TimeSlider({
    style: "width: 100%;"
   }, document.getElementById("timeSliderDiv"));
     map.setTimeSlider(timeSlider);
     
   var timeExtent = new TimeExtent();
     timeExtent.startTime = new Date("01/01/1927 UTC");
     timeExtent.endTime = new Date("12/01/1927 UTC");
     timeSlider.setThumbCount(1);// Assuming slider has only one thumb:
     timeSlider.createTimeStopsByTimeInterval(timeExtent, 1, "esriTimeUnitsMonths");
     timeSlider.setThumbIndexes([0,1]);
     timeSlider.setThumbMovingRate(1000);//for 2 sec
     timeSlider.startup();
     
   //add labels for every other time stop
   var labels = arrayUtils.map(timeSlider.timeStops, function(timeStop,i) 
   { 
    if ( i % 1 === 0 ) {
      return timeStop.getUTCMonth()+1; //to get the sliding timeline bcz getUTCMonth start from zero array
    } else {
      return "";
    }
   }); 
     
   timeSlider.setLabels(labels);
     
   timeSlider.on("time-extent-change", function(evt) {
     console.log(startTime.getUTCMonth());
    var startValString = evt.startTime.getUTCMonth();
    var endValString = evt.endTime.getUTCMonth();
    dom.byId("daterange").innerHTML = "<i>" + startValString + " and " + endValString + "<\/i>";
    console.log(startValString);
     });
  }
   
  function initSlider2() 
  { var timeSlider = new TimeSlider({
    style: "width: 100%;"
    }, document.getElementById("timeSliderDiv2"));
    map.setTimeSlider(timeSlider);
     
   var timeExtent = new TimeExtent();
    timeExtent.startTime = new Date("1/1/1927 UTC");
    timeExtent.endTime = new Date("1/31/1927 UTC");
    timeSlider.setThumbCount(1);// Assuming slider has only one thumb:
    timeSlider.createTimeStopsByTimeInterval(timeExtent, 1, "esriTimeUnitsDays");
    timeSlider.setThumbIndexes([0,1]);
    timeSlider.setThumbMovingRate(2000);//for 2 sec
    timeSlider.startup();
     
   //add labels for every other time stop
   var labels2 = arrayUtils.map(timeSlider.timeStops, function(timeStop, i) 
   { let ii = i+1;
    //console.log(timeStop);console.log(ii);
    if ( i % 1 === 0 ) {
     //return timeStop.getUTCDay(); 
     return ii; 
    }  else {
      return "";
     }
   }); 
     
   timeSlider.setLabels(labels2);
     
    timeSlider.on("time-extent-change", function(evt) {
    var startValString = evt.startTime.getUTCDay();
    var endValString = evt.endTime.getUTCDay();
    dom.byId("daterange2").innerHTML //= "<i>" + startValString + " and " + endValString  + "<\/i>";
     });
  }
  
  
          var queryTask = new QueryTask
            ("http://175.136.253.77/arcgis/rest/services/CAQM/CAQM_CO/MapServer/0");

   
  var query = new Query();
          //query.where = '1=1'; //get all data
    query.where = document.getElementById("STATE_NAME")//get from the api data
          query.returnGeometry = false;
          query.outFields = //["*"]; //to get all data column
          [ //choosen the data itself tht want to be display
            "ID", "STATION_ID", "STATION_LOCATION", "PLACE", 
            "LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"
          ];
   
    //conflict during implementation so need to change n dont used dojo on
          //on(dom.byId("execute"), "click", execute); 
    document.getElementById("execute_bttn").onclick = function() {execute_result()};

          function execute_result () 
          { 
            <!-- query.text = dom.byId("state").value; -->
            query.text = document.getElementById("state").value; //get value
   queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
   
   function showResults (results) 
     { 
    var resultItems = [];
    var resultCount = results.features.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) 
    {
      var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
      for (var attr in featureAttributes) 
      {
     resultItems.push("<b>" + attr + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[attr] + "<br>");
      }
      resultItems.push("<br>");
    }
    
    //dom.byId("info").innerHTML = resultItems.join("");
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = resultItems.join("");
    
     }
   
           } 
   
  
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="claro">

    <div id="mapDiv">
 
  <div id = "slist"><br />STATION LIST :
   <input type="text" id="state" placeholder="State"> 
   <input id="execute_bttn" type="button" value="FIND"> 
   <br />
   <br />
   <div id="info" style="padding:5px; margin:5px; background-color:#eee;">
   <br />
   <br /></div> 
  </div>
  
      <div id="bottomPanel">
        <div id="timeInfo">
    <div>Month in 1927 <span id="daterange">From Jan - Dec</span> (Completion date)</div>
          <div id="timeSliderDiv"></div>
        </div> 
      </div>
   
   <div id="bottomPanel2">
        <div id="timeInfo2">
          <div>Dates For <span id="daterange2">January 1927</span> (Completion date)</div>
          <div id="timeSliderDiv2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

[image: image : I attach the output on how it supposed to look like]